# Python Goose not able to extract mashable / usatoday / politicalwire articles

Tags: python, text-extraction, goose

I am using python goose extractor and its failing for every article on mashable.com and usatoday.com. Can someone suggest a fix for the problem?

For usatoday.com article:

```
g = Goose()
article = g.extract(url='http://www.usatoday.com/story/tech/columnist/talkingtech/2014/01/25/namm-2014---ik-multimedias-rings-to-make-music/4863193/')
assert(article.cleaned_text=='')
```

For mashable article:

```
g = Goose()
article = g.extract(url='http://mashable.com/2014/01/26/square-cofounder-jim-mckelvey/')
assert(article.cleaned_text=='')
```

For politicalwire article:

```
g = Goose()
article = g.extract(url='http://politicalwire.com/archives/2014/01/27/some_republicans_go_off_script_in_sotu_response.html')
assert(article.cleaned_text=='')
```

I assume these are pretty important websites for text extraction. Can someone suggest a fix please? Thanks

Comment: You should also assume that you're violating both sites' ToS.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of Goose from [here](https://github.com/grangier/python-goose) is able to extract from usatoday.com and mashable.com